# How to access state variable?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to access addRemoveDatabase state variable and append it to the end of the productionDatabaseData when that value is selected. I am currently getting this back and I am not to sure why.

[image]

The array is split into strings when it should be just one single string and appended to the end of that databaseArr object (databaseArr.databases)

code:

```
  const [addRemoveDatabase, setAddRemoveDatabase] = useState('iagdcaprod.auiag.corp/iadpprod')
  const [productionDatabaseData, setProductionDatabaseData] = useState([])


     const addToProduction = ({ target }, { id, databases }) => {
      
          setProductionDatabaseData((previousState) => {
      
            let newState = [...previousState]
            if (target.checked) {
              newState = [
                ...newState,
               {  unit_test_id: id, databases }
              ]
            } else {
              const i = newState.findIndex(({ unit_test_id }) => unit_test_id === id)
              if (i !== -1) newState.splice(i, 1)
            }
            return newState
          })
          const appendedArrays = [productionDatabaseData, ...props.addRemoveDatabase]
    
          
        useEffect(() => {
          console.log("databaseArr", appendedArrays);
        }, [productionDatabaseData, appendedArrays])
        }
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the addRemoveDatabase in an array.

`const [addRemoveDatabase,setAddRemoveDatabase]=useState(['iagdcaprod.auiag.corp/iadpprod'])`

I don't know what is `databases` here, but it should be a string.